# Trouble when assigning values to an alias for a QtObject

Tags: qt, qml

I am attempting to assign property values for this `QtObject` in main. However, it's not working like I think it should and I am getting an error:

`Cannot assign to non-existent property "mainValue"`

```
//main.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    id: _theWindow
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    RectComp {
        id: _theRectangleComponent
        myObject.mainValue: 5
    }
}

//RectComp.qml
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Rectangle
{
    id: _theRectangle
    width: 100
    height: 100
    anchors.centerIn: parent
    color: "lightblue"

    property alias myObject: _theObject

    QtObject
    {
        id: _theObject
        property int mainValue
    }
}
```

So apparently it doesn't like this property assignment: `myObject.mainValue: 5`. I get no error when I assign it a value this way instead:

```
RectComp 
{
  id: _theRectangleComponent
  //myObject.mainValue: 5
  Component.onCompleted
  {
    myObject.mainValue = 5
  }
}
```

If rather than giving the whole `QtObject` an alias I instead specify that the property itself should have an alias like so:

```
//property alias myObject: _theObject
property alias myObject: _theObject.mainValue
```

then when I assign it a value as I tried previously:

`myObject.mainValue: 5`

it works without an error. I think I am not setting up the `QtObject` alias correctly or something. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I would like to be able to give the `QtObject` a whole bunch of properties like: mainValue, unit, minValue, maxValue etc... but if I have to create an alias for each value then I might need to rethink how I am doing this.

Comment: Perhaps there is a race condition and the alias is not created in time before you designate an assignment? That would explain why `onCompleted` works. I've had this issue in the past and I resolved it by specifying a Singleton of a Settings QML type. Of course, that's only the way i did things - i only needed 1 copy of my object.

Comment: @TylerM If it was a race condition then it wouldn't give me the error. It would just save the value then write over top of it, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that on the left-hand side of a declarative binding expression, the QML engine is not doing any dynamic typing.

With your alias, `myObject` is seen as a `QtObject` and `QtObject` doesn't have a `mainValue` property.
This caveat doesn't happen when doing imperative assignment like on your `Component.onCompleted`.

To make this work declaratively, you have to create an explicit type for your object (so a new file). The QML engine will then be able to correctly evaluate the type and find the property.

So you need to do:

```
//RectCompInternalObject.qml
QtObject {
    property int mainValue
}
```

```
//RectComp.qml
import QtQuick 2.12

Rectangle {
    // ...
    property alias myObject: _theObject
    RectCompInternalObject {
        id: _theObject
    }
}
```